# Compile error in my parser, think I have my input file wrong, but unsure what did wrong

Tags: java, parsing, input, runtime-error, cosine-similarity

So basically this is a parser/cosine matrix calculator, but I keep getting compile error. I think I have the path for my input of reading the text file right. But it still won't compile.

**This is my main class:**

```
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.IOException;

    public class TfIdfMain {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        DocumentParser dp = new DocumentParser();
        dp.parseFiles("C:/Users/dachen/Documents/doc1.txt"); // give the location of source file
        dp.tfIdfCalculator(); //calculates tfidf
        dp.getCosineSimilarity(); //calculates cosine similarity   
    }
}
```

**My parser class:**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class DocumentParser {

    //This variable will hold all terms of each document in an array.
    private List<String[]> termsDocsArray = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    private List<String> allTerms = new ArrayList<String>(); //to hold all terms
    private List<double[]> tfidfDocsVector = new ArrayList<double[]>();

    /**
     * Method to read files and store in array.
     */
    public void parseFiles(String filePath) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        File[] allfiles = new File(filePath).listFiles();
        BufferedReader in = null;
        for (File f : allfiles) {
            if (f.getName().endsWith(".txt")) {
                in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String s = null;
                while ((s = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(s);
                }
                String[] tokenizedTerms = sb.toString().replaceAll("[\\W&&[^\\s]]", "").split("\\W+");   //to get individual terms
                for (String term : tokenizedTerms) {
                    if (!allTerms.contains(term)) {  //avoid duplicate entry
                        allTerms.add(term);
                    }
                }
                termsDocsArray.add(tokenizedTerms);
            }
        }

    }

    /**
     * Method to create termVector according to its tfidf score.
     */
    public void tfIdfCalculator() {
        double tf; //term frequency
        double idf; //inverse document frequency
        double tfidf; //term requency inverse document frequency        
        for (String[] docTermsArray : termsDocsArray) {
            double[] tfidfvectors = new double[allTerms.size()];
            int count = 0;
            for (String terms : allTerms) {
                tf = new TfIdf().tfCalculator(docTermsArray, terms);
                idf = new TfIdf().idfCalculator(termsDocsArray, terms);
                tfidf = tf * idf;
                tfidfvectors[count] = tfidf;
                count++;
            }
            tfidfDocsVector.add(tfidfvectors);  //storing document vectors;            
        }
    }

    /**
     * Method to calculate cosine similarity between all the documents.
     */
    public void getCosineSimilarity() {
        for (int i = 0; i < tfidfDocsVector.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < tfidfDocsVector.size(); j++) {
                System.out.println("between " + i + " and " + j + "  =  "
                                   + new CosineSimilarity().cosineSimilarity
                                       (
                                         tfidfDocsVector.get(i), 
                                         tfidfDocsVector.get(j)
                                       )
                                  );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**This is my error:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at DocumentParser.parseFiles(DocumentParser.java:22)
    at TfIdfMain.main(TfIdfMain.java:7)
```

Did I have the path to the text file in my document wrong?

Comment: I'm confused -- you say you're getting a compile error, but then you show a runtime exception instead. Can you clarify?

Comment: sorry I don't where the running time error is from, Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at DocumentParser.parseFiles(DocumentParser.java:22)
 at TfIdfMain.main(TfIdfMain.java:7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows filepath should use `\` instead of `/`
. Additionally there was another bug here that the code didn't need entire filepath, just the directory path. 
So instead of

```
dp.parseFiles("C:/Users/dachen/Documents/doc1.txt");
```

Should be

```
 dp.parseFiles("C:\\Users\\dachen\\Documents");
```

Comment: @mursaleen ahmad sorry mr ahmad still get the error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at DocumentParser.parseFiles(DocumentParser.java:22)
 at TfIdfMain.main(TfIdfMain.java:7)

Comment: Should you be passing the whole filename in the path? In `parseFiles` function you already do this:  `File[] allfiles = new File(filePath).listFiles();`

Comment: @MursaleenAhmad hey mr ahmad since you are the expert in Java area, can you please help me? I can't post too long on here. you mind email me? I'm really lost and need some help. I can give you my email so you won't have to give out yours. gethbonow  at gmail

Comment: @MursaleenAhmad mr ahmad I'm confused now what should I replace my path file with?

Comment: I think you just need to remove filename. Just supply the directory name. So  `dp.parseFiles("C:\\Users\\dachen\\Documents");`

Comment: Also, browse to that directory (C:\Users\dachen\Documents) in Windows and make sure that it exists.

Comment: I've updated the answer with everything we discussed here.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for `listFiles()` states that it:

> Returns null if this abstract pathname does not denote a directory

The path you are passing is not a directory.